# Alternative to "rest in peace" (RIP)

Tags: death, terminology

What should be said on the death of a Hindu, instead of RIP?

I am given to understand that religions like Christianity and Islam use the phrase RIP in relation to a dead person, so that he/she rests in his/her grave till the judgement day.

Since Hinduism has no such concept, what alternative to RIP should Hindus use (in accordance with scriptures/dharma) to offer wishes towards a dead person?

Comment: sadgati prAptirastu can be an alternative

Comment: Something like "May you attain Moksha" might suite here (preferably in Sanskrit), as in Hindus "Moksha Prapti" is considered as the ultimate goal.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal, what do you see people saying/wishing for the deceased person (preferably in rural areas) ?

Comment: @spkakkar Never observed anything like this, so I don't really know.

Comment: @LazyLubber, please write your answer, with a brief explanation. I think sadgati is the word!

Comment: @spkakkar Sadgati is used only in case of accidental deaths.Please read Sraddhatattva:)

Comment: @LazyLubber There are specific srAddha mantras.I do not think go as u like or say as u like can be advised here.

Comment: @LazyLubber sadgati praptirastu--is it correct Sanskrit even?

Comment: @commonman OP is not asking about sraddha mantras.

Comment: @LazyLubber He is asking 'for a hindu'.So wd we suggest our constructed ideas in wrong Sanskrit?

Comment: @commonman Let me know what is wrong with it.

Comment: @LazyLubber Do you know Sanskrit so that I cd try to make u understand? pl let me know that first

Comment: @commonman give it a try

Comment: @LazyLubber There are karta karma and kriya in a sentences.karta and karma should be in appropriate karaka and vibhakti and the kriya form should correspond to that.Further NO mantra can be constructed.I have tried:)

Comment: @commonman I dont think OP is asking for a mantra. He is asking for a phrase. Anyway, do you mean to say it should be sadgatiM prAptirastu?

Comment: @LazyLubber No that also is not correct I am afraid.And why shd such a prayer be made in Sanskrit at all if we are not botherd abt our mantras and scriptures? Prayer can be mentally uttered in any language!

Comment: @commonman OP is not asking for a prayer. He is asking for a phrase.

Comment: @LazyLubber i hv already told its incorrect.Bye

Answer (score 3):

Swami Vivekananda mentions :

> in Western language, a man gives up the ghost, but in our language a man gives up his body. (CW).

So  people in the Western Coutries identify the individual with the body of that individual which is buried. So there is the conecept of RIP.

The Hindus, when one dies, say that he or she has given up the body (deha-tyAga). So they cremate or burn the body and then  do the srAddha rituals for the peace of the soul. It is believed that srAddha ceremony, if properly done, pleases the pitris and the God and the departed soul is able to move to heaven and enjoy bliss there.There is the notion of rebirth also.

So there is no concept of RIP in hindu culture.

The substitute of the wishful word is 'SvadhA' which means

> sweet libation, oblation to the Manes (sanskritdictionary.com)

> The oblation of food offered to the Pitṛs or Manes of deceased
> ancestors; स्वधासंग्रहतत्पराः (svadhāsaṃgrahatatparāḥ) R.1.66;
> Ms.9.142; Y.1.12. (wisdomlib)

Comment: Thanks for your time sir. Deha-tyAga is a fact. But rest-in-peace is a wish that people make for the deceased person.  I was looking for substitute of that "wishful words".

Comment: SvadhA is the wishful word that pleases the departed soul via pleasing the pitris.You are welcome.

Comment: Okay sir. While this may be the apt word. I have a follow-up question: What do you hear people (Hindus) saying/wishing for the deceased person (preferably in rural areas) ?
Please tell from your experiences.

Comment: 'Let him/her go to heaven' (svarga). The ' Akshaya-Svarga-kamana' is there in the SrAddha also.

Comment: I don't know why I see so many people here saying that Christians or other foreigners think that a person is their body or don't believe in souls. It is a commonplace in Euro-USian culture that the soul leaves the body at death.

Comment: We don't say "left the ghost". Rather the "ghost" leaves the body. But we also say "soul" all the time. In fact Christians constantly talk about souls and many consider the idea of ghosts as superstition

Comment: I concur that it is certainly not the case that Christians, at least, identify the body with the soul.  In the west, Christians hold that the soul is one's "true being" and the body is merely a vessel.  The difference with eastern religions arises as to what happens to the soul after death.  Easterners frequently allow for the soul to continue here on Earth, often in another body (reincarnation).  Christians hold that the soul goes elsewhere at death and never comes back to Earth.  Judaism, interestingly, is famously ambiguous about what happens after death.

Comment: @Scott I prefer to have faith in the words of Swami Vivekananda.Thanks:)

Comment: @Zanna  I prefer to have faith in the words of Swami Vivekananda.

Comment: That's your choice. But I'm British and I went to two church affiliated schools (primary and secondary) and a Christian after school club as a teen. So you're denying my lifelong experience on the basis of what someone said about a religion they didn't believe in.

Comment: Mind my language? Someone is just any person. I apologise for any offence. Certainly unintended. Christianity is a young religion - perhaps it got the idea of souls from India somehow. But it is an absolutely basic and essential idea in Christianity.

Comment: You may find [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_life_(Christianity)) informative on the subject of the Christian concept of a soul.

Comment: I'm not religious, so no offense taken.  However, I live in "the bible belt" and like 90% of people around me *are* religious.  Just thought I might share my observations of religion as westerners actually live it day to day.

Answer (score 2):

We generally say 'Bhagwaan uski aatma ko shaanti de' means 'May God provide peace to his/her soul'. Since body is cremated and Soul cannot die, so the soul should have a positive/peaceful energy instead of negative/violent energy.

Comment: Namaste Shefali ji, according to my view, this phrase "aatma ko shaanti de" is semantic adoption of RIP. Modern Hindus have a total disconnect from their roots. They just copy the idea. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! You should cite sources.